# recursion in Ocaml - output unexpected result

Tags: recursion, ocaml

```
let n = read_int();;


let ftp = Hashtbl.create 1;;

let rec perrin n = 
   match n with
      0 -> 3
     |1 -> 0
     |2 -> 2
     |_ -> if Hashtbl.mem ftp n 
             then Hashtbl.find ftp n
             else
                begin 
                    Hashtbl.add ftp n (perrin (n-2) + perrin (n-3));
                    Hashtbl.find ftp  n
                 end;;


print_int (perrin n);;
print_newline ();;
```

The function works for small numbers. but for big numbers begins to return negative numbers in the result. Anyone know how to solve this?
example:

```
perrin 6443;;
```

output: returns an unexpected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, this is because of integer overflow. The perrin number 6443 is so big that it doesn't fit into the standard OCaml representation. You can switch to int64 type, but you will hit the maximum very soon. If you would like to compute perrin numbers of arbitrary length, then you should switch to some library that provide arbitrary large numbers, for example [Zarith](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/zarith).

Here is the example of the same algorithm, that computes perrin numbers using arbitrary precision numbers (using Zarith library):

```
 let ftp = Hashtbl.create 1

  let (+) = Z.add

  let rec perrin n =
    match n with
    | 0 -> Z.of_int 3
    | 1 -> Z.of_int 0
    | 2 -> Z.of_int 2
    |_ -> if Hashtbl.mem ftp n
      then Hashtbl.find ftp n
      else
        begin
          Hashtbl.add ftp n (perrin (n-2) + perrin (n-3));
          Hashtbl.find ftp  n
        end
```

And here are the results:

```
# #install_printer Z.pp_print;;
# perrin 6443;;
- : Z.t =
6937727487481534145345362428447384488478299624972546803624695551910667531554047522814387413304226129434527926499509496229770899828053746244703038130158033495659756925642507460705324476565619563726313143585381473818236243926914534542432440183345586679670347146768666345957457035004600496858722149019370892348066080092386227405747647480490430105430719428536606680584617305233160609609912020683184996768739606851007812320606992975981778299643926692143069608878875765580902743031572791438636355138605019665803104979890697923714757674707178907100143056837109943637042907642787339851137110850937972239227931113199614637067827389939915715964263895232644082473556841869600234790536494644702234455771939854947229042244627157330814752633389708917381476591438570001576028511405244641287078061574227
#
```

You may notice that the number is indeed very large, and have no chances to fit into 32 or even 64 bits. In fact, it needs 2614 bits:

```
# Z.numbits (perrin 6443);;
- : int = 2614
```

If you don't want to install `zarith` library and to add extra dependencies, then you can use OCaml builtin `Big_int` module for arbitrary precision numbers. Here is the implementation based on the `Big_int` module:

```
  open Big_int

  let ftp = Hashtbl.create 1

  let (+) = add_big_int

  let rec perrin n =
    match n with
    | 0 -> big_int_of_int 3
    | 1 -> big_int_of_int 0
    | 2 -> big_int_of_int 2
    |_ -> if Hashtbl.mem ftp n
      then Hashtbl.find ftp n
      else
        begin
          Hashtbl.add ftp n (perrin (n-2) + perrin (n-3));
          Hashtbl.find ftp  n
        end;;
```

Comment: You don't need to implement it, it is already implemented, see the link in the post. You need to install it (e.g., `opam install zarith` or `sudo apt-get install libzarith-ocaml-dev`), then you can load it in the toplevel with `#use "topfind";; #require "zarith";;`. To compile with it use `ocamlbuild` and pass `-pkg zarith` option.

Comment: actually, you can use builtin `big_int` module, instead of zarith if you don't want to mess with the installation. I've updated with an example that uses `big_int`. It should work out of box without extra work.

Comment: why return. error Unbound module Z in line 3 . I need install library Zarith on the mac osx?

Comment: Yep, if you want to use zarith library, you need to install it, and then to load it. Details vary with OS and OS configuration. Use the second example from the posting. It will work without any extra hassle :)